# XSL:FO : Repeat same table row in a loop

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

I am on the way to generate labels via XSL:FO. The labels will the same text. So my PDF page is made of a table with simply the n-times same rows until the page ends:

```
<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell>
   <fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select = "foo"/>
   </fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
  <fo:table-cell>
   <fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select = "bar"/>
   </fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

I do not want to copy and paste the code n-times to fill a page. I tried to some kind of a loop the adds n-times the row.

I found this construct:

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 20">..</xsl:for-each>
```

Did not work but raised an error.

Any easy way to loop in XSL:FO?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @martin-honnen said moments ago, but with code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to 10">
            <xsl:for-each select="$root">
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="foo" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="bar" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Inside the `<xsl:for-each select="1 to 10">`, the context is the current integer value of the `1 to 10`, and you can't select nodes relative to an integer.  You need to reestablish the context by making a variable for what was the current node and use that variable either in an inner `xsl:for-each` (as above) or in your `select` attributes.  Which is better is largely a matter of personal preference, which can come down to how many times you'd have to repeat the variable reference in `select` attributes.

---

If you are stuck with using XSLT 1.0, the `xsl:for-each` needs to be able to select enough nodes (from anywhere, really) to be able to repeat the right number of times:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="document" select="/*" />
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="(//node())[position() &lt;= 10]">
            <xsl:for-each select="$document">
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="foo" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="bar" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, IMO it would be better to instead forget about the `xsl:for-each`, etc., and do it recursively:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/*" name="row">
        <xsl:param name="count" select="1" />
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="foo" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="bar" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <xsl:if test="$count &lt; 10">
            <xsl:call-template name="row">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailled response. My code fails as the parser calls `to`and `20`illegal token. 
Also I read
`#NUMBER cannot be converted to NodeList`

Comment: It looks like you're not really using XSLT 2.0 after all.  What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I use FOP 2.3 on a Windows machine for development.

Comment: You are running an XSLT 1.0 processor.  FOP uses Xalan: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.3/running.html#check-input. Xalan implements XSLT 1.0: http://xalan.apache.org/index.html.  Give me a minute and I'll add an XSLT 1.0 version.

Comment: Thanks, Tony. Works perfect!

Comment: Which one did you use?